# python: converting datetime format

Tags: python

I have the following format:

`"Wed Jun 25 15:38:29 PDT 2014"` and I would like to convert it to `"2014-06-25 15:38:29"`, i.e. `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`

Code:

```
import time

import datetime


rawtime = "Wed Jun 25 15:38:29 PDT 2014"

dt = time.strptime(rawtime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

print dt
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: time data 'Wed Jun 25 15:38:29 PDT 2014\n' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Comment: You have to specify the format *the string is currently in* for `strptime`, not the format you want it to be!

Answer (score 3):

Simplest solution using [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) package. It really is excellent at this.

```
from dateutil import parser
print parser.parse("Wed Jun 25 15:38:29 PDT 2014")
```

Output:

```
2014-06-25 15:38:29
```

Answer (score 1):

First install pytz:

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade pytz
```

Then

```
import datetime
from pytz import timezone
rawtime = "Wed Jun 25 15:38:29 PDT 2014"
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(rawtime,'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y')
print(d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Should return:

```
2014-06-25 15:38:29
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey So i found a solution for 95% of your problem.

```
import time
import datetime

rawtime = "Wed Jun 25 15:38:29 2014"
dt = time.strptime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y",rawtime)
print dt
```

this will out `time.struct_time(tm_year=2014, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=25, tm_hour=15, tm_min=38, tm_sec=29, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=176, tm_isdst=-1)`

After this you just need to create a string and place them in the right order you want. The only thing I wasn't sure of how to do off the top of my head was the PDT part of it.

To save the dt as a variable you can do

```
x = str(dt.tm_year) + "-" + str(dt.tm_mon) + "-" + str(dt.tm_mday) + " " + str(dt.tm_hour) + ":" + str(dt.tm_min) + ":" + str(dt.tm_sec)
print x
```

this will output `2014-6-25 15:38:29`

Good luck!

Comment: there is still the issue of the PDT thing: this what i got:  (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Wed Jun 25 15:38:29 PDT 2014\n' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'

Comment: there is still the issue of the PDT thing: this what i got:  (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Wed Jun 25 15:38:29 PDT 2014\n' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'::: Okay i did strip the PDT off the string and now:        line = line.replace("PDT", "")
                rawtime = line
                dt = time.strptime(rawtime,'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y' )    print dt shows time.struct_time(tm_year=2014, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=25, tm_hour=15, tm_min=38, tm_sec=29, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=176, tm_isdst=-1) now should i do a formatting one more time to put it in %Y=%m-%d %H:%M:%S??

Comment: So @dody to complete it you just save it in a variable `x = str(dt.tm_year) + "-" + str(dt.tm_mon) + "-" + str(dt.tm_mday) + " " + str(dt.tm_hour) + ":" + str(dt.tm_min) + ":" + str(dt.tm_sec)` hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the `PDT` part:

```
import time
import datetime

rawtime = "Wed Jun 25 15:38:29 PDT 2014"
times = rawtime.split(' ')
del times[4]
dt = time.strptime(' '.join(times), '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
print time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", dt)
```

Should get you:

```
2014-06-25 15:38:29
```

Answer (score 0):

`pip install python-dateutil`:

```
In [56]: from dateutil import parser

In [57]: parser.parse("Wed Jun 25 15:38:29 PDT 2014").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
Out[57]: '2014-06-25 15:38:29'
```

Or manually:

```
In [58]: d = time.strptime("Wed Jun 25 15:38:29 PDT 2014","%a %b %d %H:%M:%S PDT %Y")

In [59]: "{}-{:02}-{:02} {:02}:{:02}:{:02}".format(d.tm_year,d.tm_mon,d.tm_mday,d.tm_hour,d.tm_min,d.tm_sec)
Out[59]: '2014-06-25 15:38:29'
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you need to call [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) or use [dateutil](http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil) to parse date strings. However in this case, `rawtime` looks similar enough to a date as specified by the [RFC 2822 (Internet Message Format)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822.html#page-14) that it can parsed using the standard library function [email.utils.parsedate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parsedate):

```
import email.utils as EU
import datetime as DT

rawtime = "Wed Jun 25 15:38:29 PDT 2014"
timetup = EU.parsedate(rawtime)
# (2014, 6, 25, 15, 38, 29, 0, 1, -1)

date = DT.datetime(*timetup[:6])
print(date)
# 2014-06-25 15:38:29
```